# how to dynamically create templates in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

New to angularjs so I'm not sure how to best phrase this question so this may be a duplicate.  I have a table that I want to populate with a label and some check boxes.  Each row represents a test metric with two checkboxes indicating "pass" or "fail"

```
function ListController($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {name: 'Feature X', flash: false, html: false},
        {name: 'Feature Y', flash: false, html: false}
    ];
}
```

I've got the table populating correctly, but what I'm not sure about is how can create this table dynamically?  I want to be able to submit this data and create a new table when a new test is selected.  The only way I can see right now to invoke this function is on the initialization of the document and I can't see how I can pass in any additional values to change the "items" node based on the test. fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Lcue/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$resource`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) to submit/retrieve data from the server:

```
app = angular.module("Test", ["ngResource"])

function ListController($scope, $resource) {
    var Test = $resource("/tests/:id", {id: "@id"});
    $scope.items = Test.query()

    $scope.addTest: function() {
        $scope.items.push($scope.newTest)
        $scope.newTest = {}
    }
}
```

and then bind `newTest.name`, `newTest.flash`, `newTest.html` in your view using `ng-model`.

Comment: ultimately that would be ideal +1.  In the short term, is there a way to pass in a value or create a template via function call?

Comment: @Shane in that case, the example is the same omitting the $resource part. Bind the `newTest` fields in your view and use the `addTest` method.